# Aspects of Kamala Das's Poem 'My Mother at Sixty-Six'

Tags: poetry, wording-choice, kamala-surayya

This poem ['My Mother at Sixty-Six'](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lefl111.pdf) is in our curriculum and I have a few questions on this:

1. Why does the poet capitalise 'Young Trees'? Why not just leave it as 'young trees' as it is not a proper noun?
2. Why has the poet chosen the age of sixty-six for the title of the poem and as the age of the mother? Why not any other number?
3. What is the purpose of placing the word 'pain; in a separate line? (It looked as if the word wrapping had made it look like that but it seems it's been intentionally left.)

---

EDIT: Regarding the 3rd question: it is sourced from [here](https://cbseacademic.nic.in/web_material/SQP/ClassXII_2023_24/EnglishCore-SQP.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. She capitalizes "Young / Trees" for emphasis, to heighten the contrast with her mother, who "was as old as she / looked." Also, if the words had just been "young / trees sprinting," then "Young" would apply only to the trees. As Das has written it, the word could be a metonym for all the youthful things the speaker sees: not only the sprinting trees, but also the children spilling out of their homes.
2. Das's poems are known to be largely autobiographical. Presumably her real-life mother was 66 when she wrote that poem? That's the simplest explanation that comes to mind. I'm unaware of any particular significance to the age 66 in Indian society, unlike (say) 60 or 80, which are marked as special turning points.
3. The textbook reprints the poem unforgivably poorly. The word wrap makes nonsense of the actual line divisions. The version at the [English for Students website](https://www.english-for-students.com/my-mother-at-sixty-six.html) makes clear that "pain" is not in fact on a line by itself, it's the last word of a line.

Comment: I get you, but in a question paper I have linked in my edit the 3rd question has been asked.

Comment: @HarikrishnanM The fact that the question paper repeats the error from the textbook doesn't make your Q3 any more answerable in terms of the poem itself, alas. This site can only deal with the poem as it is. Errors made by the NCERT, or by those who set board exam papers, are out of scope here. If you have the misfortune to encounter this particular question when **you** sit your high-stakes board exams, I suggest making up some guff about how the word isolated by itself mirrors the isolation of the old lady, or something. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I get your point now...

Comment: I mean, yeah, you can't very well write "It isn't on a line by itself, the question is wrong and based on poor typesetting" in a board exam answer. But that is the correct answer. And here, we can tell you only the correct answer. To satisfy the CBSE board, you will have to make up something plausible yourself, and what you make up is up to you. The chances of their asking the same question again aren't that high, though, so you'll probably be okay. In any event, I wish you every success!